# List of equations in separate pdf

Tags: equations, theorems

I am communication with my coauthors via email. This time, I am the author, so I send them the PDF file of the document, and they send me corrections. Then I'd like to implement these corrections. They are of the form:

> In Equation (3.2) blah blah
>   In Theorem C blah blah

So now, what I'd like to have is a list of equations in a separate window. I would click on the appropriate entry in the list, which would then take me to the equation in my document's PDF (using Okular, if that's important), and then I could make the appropriate changes in the `.tex` file.

Presently, when I read "In Equation (3.2) change...", I need to scroll to Equation (3.2), make a small change then see the next error. And there are about a hundred small errors like this.

To make the system perfect, it would be great if the list of equations would automatically update itself when I make a change in the `.tex` file and run `pdflatex`.

Clearly, I'd like to have something similar for theorem-like environments.

Comment: Is it possible to add a simple [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier to post precise answer and reproduce your situation otherwise it would guess/conceptual work.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to know what you are using to create your `LaTeX` documents.  I can only give you advice which is Emacs specific but maybe I will be lucky and that is what you are using.

This will allow you to jump to the lines in the `.tex` document by holding `shift` and left clicking the equation in your `pdf`.

Open Okular and go to settings-Configure Okular.  A new window will open, and at the bottom, you will see Editors.  There will be a drop down menu of editors you can select.  In my case, I would select Emacs.

Since you are using Okular, I am going to guess you are on a Linux system.  You need to set up your software to open in server mode.  Again, I will be using Emacs as the example.  In my `~/.bashrc`, I have the following:

```
#  Emacs-server mode and non-GUI alias
alias emacs='emacsclient -t --alternate-editor='
```

This starts Emacs in server mode and I run Emacs from the terminal not the GUI.

Next, you need to set up synctex.  I use `LaTeXMK` so I will be using it for the example of what you need to do.  In my `~/.emacs`, I have

```
;; ============ Latexmk setup ==============                                        
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
                 (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error 
                                   -synctex=1' -pdf %O %S" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
        (demolish-tex-help)
        (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))
```

You will see that `-synctex=1` is set during the compile.

Then I had to make adjustments for Okular and settings in my custom-set-variables in my `~/.emacs` file.

Okular adjustments:

```
;; Set okular to open with C-c C-v view option                                      
(defun Okular-make-url () (concat
     "file://"
     (expand-file-name (funcall file (TeX-output-extension) t)
                       (file-name-directory (TeX-master-file))
                       "#src:"
                       (TeX-current-line)
                       (expand-file-name (TeX-master-directory))
                       "./"
                       (TeX-current-file-name-master-relative))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda ()
        (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
                     '("%u" Okular-make-url))))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("Okular" "okular --unique %u")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular")))
```

`custom-set-variables` adjustments:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                                      
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                   
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                          
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                              
 '(TeX-PDF-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular -unique %o#src:%n%b"))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "Okular"))))
)
```

Finally, I had to set up my `~./latexmkrc` file for synctex.

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S -file-line-error -synctex=1';
```

With this set up, I can click anywhere in my `pdf` and jump to the line my `.tex` file without having to scroll.

Basically, for whatever editor you are using, you need to set up `synctex` and Okular to use synctex for this to work.

To address your question on a list of the equations, you could use `RefTeX` which is a plugin for `AUCTeX` that comes with Emacs.  Again, I don't know what editor you are using though.  If you are using Emacs, I can update my answer with how to use `RefTeX` to show the equations in a separate buffer.  Then you can hit `r` to rescan as you change your equations.

This isn't exactly what you asked for but it would work in simplifying your work load.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I do use emacs/auctex, so the above is very helpful.  I didn't know how this forum works, so actually I just noticed all these comments.

Comment: Did this post answer your question? If so, edit your question, so it can be reopened now that we know what you were looking for.